# Output array php to get a variable to use in a conditional statement

Tags: php

I am using this code, the best I can write without actually ever seeing an example or one close enough for my brain to understand.

This works, but it could improve. The problem is that I have a custom multicheck and its options are 'post' and/or 'page'. So I am checking the array and creating a variable. There must be another way.

```
function theme_prefix_featured_image() {

    $show = get_theme_mod( 'auto_add_featured_image', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    $size = get_theme_mod( 'featured_image_size' );

    if ( ! has_post_thumbnail() || ! is_singular() || empty( $show ) || empty( $size ) ) return;

    $post_types = $caption = '';

    /// HERE IS THE AREA BEGIN
    if ( in_array( 'post', $show ) ) :
        $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'post' ) );
    endif;

    if ( in_array( 'page', $show ) ) :
        $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'page' ) );
    endif;

    if ( in_array( 'post', $show ) && in_array( 'page', $show ) ) :
        $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'post', 'page' ) );
    endif;
    /////// HERE IS THE AREA END

    //Get Caption
    $caption = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt;

    if ( $post_types ): //// TO CREATE THE CONDITIONAL

        if ( ! empty( $caption ) ) :
            $caption = sprintf( '<figcaption>%s</figcaption>', $caption );
        endif;

        $image = genesis_get_image( array(
            'format'  => 'html',
            'size'    => $size,
            'context' => '',
            'attr'    => '',
        ) );

        printf( '<figure class="featured-image aligncenter">%s%s</figure>', $image, $caption );


    endif;

}
```

Comment: Personally I would use something like: `$post_arr=array_intersect(array('post', 'page'), get_theme_mod( 'auto_add_featured_image', array( 'post', 'page' )) );` along with `if (!empty($post_arr) && is_singular($post_arr)) {...`.

Comment: You'd need to delete `empty($show)` but that case is covered with `!empty($post_arr)`.

Comment: I'm going to give yours a whirl. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be sufficient:

```php
$post_types = is_singular( array_intersect( array ( 'post', 'page' ), $show ) );
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. That is significantly better. I had never see this before and wouldn't have come up with it in a zillion years.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can combine the if statements, like this:

```
if ( in_array( 'post', $show ) ){   
    if ( in_array( 'page', $show ) ){
        //in both post and page
        $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'post', 'page' ) );
    }else{
        //in only post
        $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'post' ) );
    }
}else if ( in_array( 'page', $show ) ){
    //in only page
    $post_types = is_singular( array ( 'page' ) );
}else{
    //undefined.
}
```

This will be a tiny bit more efficient as it doesn't have to check the other if's is one passes.  So you are checking  1 or 2 statements instead of 3.

One note and this makes it more clear if it's in none of the above then `$post_types` is undefined, which probably is not a good thing.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a spin and come back to select. I like that it's more efficient.